# I couldn't get the current userid using get_currentuserinfo() in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new in wordpress, I am created a wordpress api using WP REST API .
I created a custom route in the api but in the callback i didn't get the current user id and user details using the function `get_currentuserinfo()`

Comment: Did you want to use such function in rest api or in wordpress site?

Answer (score 1):

> In Wordpress 4.5 this function **get_currentuserinfo()** has been deprecated

**Replace**

```
get_currentuserinfo()
```

With

```
wp_get_current_user();
```

Deprecated Info found Here : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_currentuserinfo/

Have a try for this. You will get the Current User Information .

Comment: i used the both function still i didn't get the result. The api is used for login also.

Comment: Use this function a check `get_current_user_id()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
 $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
 $user_id = $current_user->ID;
```

*Read More [**Here**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user)*